# Array_push doesn't make new key, instead replaces current value

Tags: php, arrays, forms, session

I'm kinda lost here.

So here is what i'm trying to do.
I have a session, that's called "test", i have set the session to be an array every time that $_POST['process'] isset.

The $_POST['process'] is containing a integer, that's fetched from a DB Table.

Here's my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['process']))
{
  $_SESSION['test'] = array();
  $array_merge = array_push($_SESSION['test'], $_POST['process']);
}
```

It work's at first time, here's the result:

> [test] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => 21311
>           )

I was expecting, that it would create a new key, and assign it to the other value that get's fetched from $_POST['process'] - but instead it just overwrites the 0 key.

What am i doing wrong here?

Kind regards

Comment: Enable error reporting and error handling on the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're writing `$_SESSION['test'] = array();` which is resetting the value of `$_SESSION['test']` to an empty array. Therefore it has removed your previous value and have put in your new one.

To fix this check if `$_SESSION['test']` is already set, if it's not do `$_SESSION['test'] = array();`, otherwise just insert new values.

Full example:

```
if(isset($_POST['process'])) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
        $_SESSION['test'] = array();
    }

    $array_merge = array_push($_SESSION['test'], $_POST['process']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is one precise case where using `array_push()` is a disadvantage versus its alternative square bracket syntax.

`array_push()` requires you to declare the empty array in advance; `[]` will not AND it is functionless AND it is more brief to code.

Furthermore, I am nearly 100% sure that you don't actually want to know the new element count after pushing. The [PHP Manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

> Returns the new number of elements in the array.

...so, if you do want to know the new count, then perhaps rename your variable from `$array_merge` to `$array_size` or `$array_count` or `$array_length`.

I know I wouldn't want to write an extra condition just to declare an empty variable then use a function to add a new element, especially when it can be done in one line

```
if(isset($_POST['process'])) {
  $_SESSION['test'][] = $_POST['process'];  // all done
}
```

This will work the first time and every time as desired.